# How to call a function if the Firebase data changes using Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I need to call a function when a Firebase value changes in javascript,
I tried looking for a function like `onDataSetChanged` in Javascript but didn't find any.

Answer (score 3):

Use the on() or once() methods of `firebase.database.Reference` to observe events, as detailed here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events

For example you could do:

```
var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('posts/' + postId + '/starCount');
starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  yourFunction();  //<- call your function here
});
```

or

```
var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('posts/' + postId);
starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  yourFunction(snapshot.val().postAuthor);  //<- example, we pass the author of the Post to the function
});
```

If you want to pass a value from the snapshot as a parameter of your function